# Window ToolBar items does not displayes MenuItems

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have following problem:

I have few menu items 
in window toolbar  that enables depends on active view. For this I wrote property tester. And check that it works well and all MenuItems is set to visible true, so they should be visible. But items is not shown unless window is re-sized or other toolbars are moved.

What is the problem? I think that after resizing method like repaint or update is called. Do I need to call it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If resize helps, it means that you have a layout problem. Just call `layout(true)` on the parent component. If that still doesn't help, the problem could be in the parent of the parent, or parent of parent of parent, and so on. In worst case, call layout on the shell.

Reason: the parent (or one of the parents) don't know the size of the child has changed and the toolbar needs now more space.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call `IToolBarManager.update()` to get the tool bar updated when visibility changes.

Comment: This call does not help